Is the grass greener on the other side?
Is it? I suspect that with different angles and such (but ignoring the basic structure of grass; resulting in you seeing mostly brown earth if you look straight down on grass) this might perhaps be true.
Does physics have something to say about it? (What does it even mean, this "greener"?)
To be specific: Is the same grass greener if you move it from 8 meters away to 40 meters away? You are standing up and your eyes are at a height of 1.6 meters.

That depends greatly on the sun angle, grass blade geometry relative to the ground, the specific biology of your specific eyes (since color perception is subjective based on cone/rod content in the eye), what exactly is in the grass…

@controlgroup Interesting that biology bit. And I do see different bands of greens on sports fields (presumably from mowing in a different direction), although I wouldn't quite know which are the "greener" ones. :)

What do you mean by "greener"? What are the lighting conditions? What type of grass are you considering? Can you be more specific?

Average landscapes may actually be greener at middle distances (farther than the range specified in this question), as shown by Figures 3 & 12 of "Hue contrast and the sense of space". I did not vote to close and would certainly vote to reopen if this question were changed so it included Figure 3c from that article and essentially just asked how much of it can be explained by physics instead of just being an artifact of photographer selection bias.

@VincentThacker "The grass is greener on the other side" is an English saying. I'm just curious whether a statement like that could be somehow substantiated in a physics sense. For fun, and perhaps for some interesting insights.

Grass that is observed from a distance with the sun over your shoulder shows whitish specular reflection highlights from the grass blades that wash out the color, making the green color much less intense than when you look closely at the grass in the shade.
Grass that is observed while looking in the direction of the sun shows transmitted light that the grass blades have filtered, which lacks the specular reflection highlights and is much more pure and intense. Ex-photographers like me know this trick and can make use of it to make the green foliage "pop" when shooting landscape scenes.
